# Encontrar patrón en cmd de Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, grep

Tengo un problema. Tengo un fichero log.txt con muchas líneas entre las cuales se encuentra el texto "Active Batches (0)". 
´Quiero obtener el valor entre paréntesis por línea de comandos en Windows (prompt) y almacenarlo en una variable var. En linux sería utilizando el comando grep de la siguiente manera:

var=$(grep -Po '(?<=Active Batches\s()\d+(?=))' < log.txt)

Me gustaría saber como hacer esto mismo en el cmd de Windows con la funcion find,findstr o similar

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell tiene select-string que dicen es semejante a grep.   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6 Busqué para la información en español pero no la encontré.

Comment: Gracias pero necesito que sea con la línea de comandos CMD no con PowerShell. Con findstr o algún comando parecido que estuviese disponible en el prompt de windows.